# TruncMinute Celery TaskResult

Tags: django, django-celery

I am trying to display statistics about the ["django-celery-results"](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-results/)
I need a list to use for chartjs.

```
last_records = TaskResult.objects.filter(task_name='scraper.tasks.send_game', date_created__day=20).order_by("-date_created")[:100]
queryset = last_records.annotate(date=TruncMinute('date_created')).values("date_created").annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
```

I made this query however its not returning the correct response. There are many records so thats why I limit it to last 100 records.
In order to use chartjs correctly, I need a list of the date with the hour and how many records there are of it.
I need something like this:

```
[{'date_created': '2021-02-20 10:49'), 'count': 2}, ...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this:

```
five_minutes_ago = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=-120)

last_records = TaskResult.objects.filter(
            task_name='scraper.tasks.send_game', date_done__gte=five_minutes_ago
            ).annotate(date=TruncMinute('date_done')).values("date").annotate(
                amount=Count('id')
            ).order_by("-date")
```